# Problems aligning 2 divs horizontally

Tags: alignment

my site is: http://www.italianiaperth.com/

i am trying to align the text in white 'Italiani a Perth' and the search Widget horizontally.. (text floating left, search widget to the right)

I have managed to get them on the same line by setting their respect divs width to auto but the problem is the content underneath floats to the right along with the search widget

ive played with this for hours and looked at similar questions on the forums but im at my witts end, can someone point me in the right direction? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap 3.0 ( getbootstrap.com )

Put the two divs like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8"> DIV LEFT </div>
   <div class="col-md-8"> DIV RIGHT </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info here :
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid